# Java LDAP - TCP RST and socket handle leak

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

We have a Java Ldap client which creates a conn and bind to AD(Active Directory). This conn is kept open for future use. After idle timeout(15 min) AD closes conn by sending **TCP RST**. When such a conn is used later, ldap operations will fail as expected. On such failures we explicitly close ldap connections. But these socket handles are not getting released and end up in *can't identify protocol* state in **lsof** output. **strace** indicates that explicit **close** on such failed ldap handles are not resulting in socket close system calls.

In some cases AD closes idle connection by sending **FIN**. In such cases LDAP library itself is cleanly closing conn and this issue is not happening.

Is this a bug in Java Ldap library? Are there any solutions ?

## Test Code to reproduce the issue

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;

public class Ldap {

        public static DirContext connect(String host, String port, String bindDn, String password) throws NamingException {
                        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                String ldapUrl = "ldap://" + host + ":" + port;

                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindDn);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
                env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");

            return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                        System.out.println("Ldap connect....");
                        DirContext conn = connect("ipaddress", "389", "user@domain.com", "password");
                        System.out.println("Sleep - active ldap conn");
                        Thread.sleep(18 * 60 * 1000);
                        System.out.println("Closing conn...");
                        conn.close();
                        System.out.println("Sleep for ever...");
                        Thread.sleep(60 * 10 * 60 * 1000);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

## Ldap Thread(RST)

```
recvfrom(5, 0x7ffd27274540, 8192, 0, 0, 0) = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
lseek(3, 43442010, SEEK_SET)            = 43442010
read(3, "PK\3\4\n\0\0\0\0\0\321\205\222E\241\375N\256\204\1\0\0\204\1\0\0&\0\0\0", 30) = 30
lseek(3, 43442078, SEEK_SET)            = 43442078
read(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0003\0\25\1\0\3()V\1\0\25(Ljava/lang/S"..., 388) = 388
recvfrom(5, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL)    = 0
sendto(5, "0\5\2\1\2B\0", 7, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xd)                       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
sendto(5, "0\5\2\1\2B\0", 7, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xd)                       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
mmap(0x7ffd27185000, 12288, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7ffd27185000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
madvise(0x7ffd27185000, 1028096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
_exit(0)                                = ?
Process 47983 detached
```

## Ldap Thread(FIN)

```
recvfrom(5, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL)    = 0
gettimeofday({1451376987, 341537}, NULL) = 0
sendto(5, "0\5\2\1\2B\0", 7, 0, NULL, 0) = 7
dup2(4, 5)                              = 5
close(5)                                = 0
mmap(0x7fc3f8984000, 12288, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3f8984000
gettimeofday({1451376987, 342129}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
madvise(0x7fc3f8984000, 1028096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
_exit(0)
```

Comment: If you want to do serious LDAP work I would recommend using a LDAP SDK. UnboundID is my favorite.

Comment: @jwilleke I keep reading this but I never see a good reason why. I'm doing some pretty hairy LDAP stuff, all within JNDI plus a few hand-written controls. It would be nice if JNDI supoorted the full set of LDAP controls, even the draft ones, and I have an RFE in to that effect, but I'm not aware of anything much else that a special purpose SDK would solve.

Comment: The UnboundID Java SDK will change your life. There are Many features that you will no longer need to perform as they are builtin. As one example, these are the "ServerSets" DNSSRVRecordServerSet, FailoverServerSet, FastestConnectServerSet, FewestConnectionsServerSet, RoundRobinDNSServerSet, RoundRobinServerSet, SingleServerSet which allows many different types of pooling and load balancing abilities. https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is here:

> This conn is kept open for future use.

Don't do that. This is poor practice. You're tying up resources at the server. You should just obtain JNDI contexts when you need them and close them immediately afterwards. You can mitigate the adverse effects of that by enabling [JNDI LDAP connection pooling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html#POOL) in the Java code, but with a much shorter timeout than 15 minutes. Then the issue of receiving an RST cannot arise. I've been running an LDAP client along these lines for six years without any leaks.

Comment: OK. Any idea why Java LDAP client is not closing socket properly on RST. Is this a bug in SDK ? If we are closing conn soon after use, won't these sockets go to TIME_WAIT state(which could be a problem if there is a continuous burst of ldap requests for a long period of time).

Comment: @Anoop It looks like a bug and if I could remember the investigation I did six years ago it is entirely possible that I've already encountered it. You will indeed get TIME_WAIT states but the alternative of leaking sockets is worse. You need to set the connection pool timeout high enough to minimize this. I would suggest five or ten minutes.